# Defining Lua methods as initialization

Tags: methods, lua, initializer

In the Lua language, I am able to define functions in a table with something such as

```
table = { myfunction = function(x) return x end }
```

I wondered if I can created methods this way, instead of having to do it like

```
function table:mymethod() ... end
```

I am fairly sure it is possible to add methods this way, but I am unsure of the proper name of this technique, and I cannot find it looking for "lua" and "methods" or such.

My intention is to pass a table to a function such as `myfunction({data= stuff, name = returnedName, ?method?init() = stuff})`.

Unfortunately I have tried several combinations with the colon method declaration but none of them is valid syntax.

So...anyone here happens to know?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sure: `table:method()` is just syntactic sugar for `table.method(self)`, but you have to take care of the `self` argument. If you do

```
tab={f=function(x)return x end }
```

then `tab:f(x)` won't work, as this actually is `tab.f(tab,x)` and thus will return `tab` instead of `x`.

You might take a look on the [lua users wiki on object orientation](http://lua-users.org/wiki/ObjectOrientationTutorial) or [PiL chapter 16](http://www.lua.org/pil/16.html).

Comment: Oh it works. ...there was I searching for a convoluted solution when it is that simple. Ahem. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Just a comment - when making "methods", the first parameter is usually named 'self'. This is what the function tab:method() syntactic sugar does. If you want to call it through ':', create your function as such: tab = { f = function(self, x) return x end } and call as tab:f(x).